# Split function Issue

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a rather simple question however I cannot seem to find the issue.

I am using the below Split function, however, when I have an account number leading with 0 it automatically deletes the zero as it is interpreted as a number, not as text, however I have tried implementing to text function but as account number vary in sizes and not standard then I might have some accounts with more 0 than it supposed to have. I have also tried other ways however nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Code using:

```
=SPLIT(A2, "Account Number: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use regex:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "Account Number: (.*)")
```

[image: 0]

or:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(A1&"♥", "Account Number: "), "♥", )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, they both worked perfectly, could you please tell me what the (.*) in the   =REGEXEXTRACT is and also the "♥" in the =SUBSTITUTE Function do exactly?

Comment: `(.*)` - means "everything". the ♥ symbol is just unique symbol - it has no significance eg can be anything ♂♀♫☼►♣♠♦♪.... the reason is to prevent converting numbers to numeric which SPLIT does. if you add some text/symbol to it its treated as Plain text/string instead of numeric value

Comment: Nice one Thanks for explaining these!